What is this red disc component
what is this part in the photo called?

Can you [edit] the question to clarify if you are trying to identify the "red disc" component, or something else?

a "late component"? A component that has gone to meet its maker. If someone hadn't soldered it to the board, it would be pushing up the daisies! (No seriously, that looks like a disc capacitor or a current limitor/ varistor, but if it was a capacitor, there would be a designation "C{number}" next to it; and the fact that it exploded that badly means that there's almost certainly more damaged components on that board, which, being conformally coated, probably is hard to impossible to service)

The board purpose would help with interface specs even more

@MarcusMüller I didn't know conformally coated boards were that hard to service. I guess it's good no-one told me, since I've done it multiple times. It's annoying but not that bad. Once the solder melts from the iron, either the conformal coating burns off or crumbles off. And sharp meter probes poke through.

@BenjiWiebe well, "hard" is just the flip side of "annoying", I'd say. But sure, it's possible with a good iron and a fume extractor, ideally.

@BenjiWiebe what worries me more is that the metal heatsink was conformally coated. Not sure that is compatible with the purpose of a heat sink…

it is a lincoln electric 230v welder main control board

It's an exploded overvoltage protection  polycrystalline semiconductor that costs about $1 Get an MOV with a holding voltage greater than your grid voltage.  But it should be protected also by a Polyfuse, a thermal fuse or a resettable breaker.

from what i heard an not smart person forced a 240 v turn lock plug into a 480v turn lock never thought it was possiable until now.it looks like there are 2 traces the got vaporized how do i test transistors? im thinking fixing the board since once fixed it will be worth $750 and i can home use it as well. also how do i know what kind of wire to replace traces with? links would help in tracking down parts.

i put more information on the orignal post.

This is about three separate questions in one: what is the red thing; what about the traces; what else has blown; etc. The original question has already been answered, and note that this edit would invalidate those existing answers. Allowing this, would not well respect the effort that they have volunteered here.  The format of this site is not so much an ongoing conversation, but rather a simple question-response. You are welcome, however, to ask those (sub-)questions separately. Don't forget to upvote / select as answer, any answer(s) that you feel have answered the question well. Cheers :)

@AG  Questions should be as good quality as you can make them - all available information, good photos etc. This is because the system automatically blocks people with a low reputatoion score and multiple low quality questions from asking more questions until the old ones are fixed. I'm a moderator but we have no control over this process and we do nmot even know the exact criteria for this being applied or removed. During the recent question and answers your account temporarily went into a "blocked from asking" state - but this reset when votes etc changed.

BTW, if you try to repair it and fail, do some googling. There's places that repair welder circuit boards for less than the price of a new one (and if it's an old welder, the board might not be available new anymore).

The broken red component is most likely an ICL (inrush current limiter). That 'T' in TP1 may mean "thermistor". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current_limiter
But it may also be an MOV (Metal Oxide Varistor).
If it's in series with current, it's an ICL. If it's in parallel with a voltage, it's an MOV.

I'd say TVS or MOV. If you mean the red component. But we don't yet know for sure which component OP means.

(Test Point being pointless, another guess is Transient Protection)

Almost certainly a MOV (Metal Oxide Varistor). The red colour was once most common (General Electric (GE) was once the dominant manufacturer with the product dubbed the GE-MOV, and red was their colour).
Image below from here

The failure mode (excessive leakage, followed by catastrophic failure with some fireworks) is also very much typical of these devices.
There is not necessarily anything else wrong, other than perhaps a blown fuse, these things can just fail as shown after they've seen enough abuse for their lifetime. On the other hand, they don't clamp particularly well, so the rest of the circuitry may have taken a grave 'hit' at the same time if there was a large transient or an improper supply connection.

Yes, it is most likely a MOV. They typically fail open circuits, often splitting in half when they release the magic smoke. You can remove it; the device should function if the circuit is not damaged. The MOV is a passive component and does not activate until it reaches the clamping voltage.

so with half of it missing how do identify it so i can replace it? the oringal post has been updated to show more information.

Begin by identifying the operating voltage. MOVs are positioned across the power input or output terminals. Ascertain the device's maximum working voltage. You need to select an MOV with the appropriate operating voltage and, for size, choose one that is the same physical size or larger. Keep in mind the circuit does not require it to operate normally.

It's an exploded overvoltage protection  polycrystalline semiconductor that costs about $1 Get an MOV with a holding voltage greater than your grid voltage.   This one is rated to withstand 275Vac https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/panasonic-electronic-components/ERZ-V10D431/162603
It is flash gold-plated PCB with gunk plastered all over everything including the heatsinks, significantly reducing their thermal performance but perhaps protecting it from a dusty environment.
It should also be protected by a Polyfuse, a thermal fuse, or a resettable breaker. If it fails during a lightning storm, which happens frequently, buy spares.
